# Cleaning VBA code to reference code instead of duplicating it

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a form for entering product information that works and would like to clean it up.  Currently for every product division, I have copied and pasted the same code to take the values from the form and apply them to the correct division sheet.  I would like to have the code occur once, and then reference it in the code for the 22 divisions.  I have not been able to find a solution to this, likely because I do not know the proper terminology.

Here is a section of what I would like to fix:

```
Case "DIVISION 21 - FIRE SUPPRESSION"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-21")

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value


Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value


Case "DIVISION 23 - HEATING VENTILATING AND AIR CONDITIONING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-23")

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value


Case "DIVISION 26 - ELECTRICAL"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-26")

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value


Case "DIVISION 27 - COMMUNICATIONS"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-27")

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value
```

Here is what I would like to do if possible:

```
[Refrence Code]=

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value


Case "DIVISION 21 - FIRE SUPPRESSION"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-21")

[Refrence code]


Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")

[Refrence code]


Case "DIVISION 23 - HEATING VENTILATING AND AIR CONDITIONING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-23")

[Refrence code]


Case "DIVISION 26 - ELECTRICAL"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-26")

[Refrence code]


Case "DIVISION 27 - COMMUNICATIONS"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-27")

[Refrence code]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  If possible, please explain in a clear and detailed way since I am still very much a novice at VBA coding and a beginner at coding in general.

Comment: Move the repetitive block outside the `Select Case`.

Comment: Will your sheet names always start with `DIVISION - ## `?

Comment: Sheets are listed as Div-21, Div-22, Div-23, Div-26, & Div-27.  There are gaps in the numbering as not all divisions apply to products so are not included in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that changes is `ws`. Keep the `Select Case` and move the repetitive block afterwards.

```
    Case "DIVISION 21 - FIRE SUPPRESSION"
         Set ws = Sheets("Div-21")
    Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
         Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")
    Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
         Set ws = Sheets("Div-23")
    ...
    Case Else
         ' handle other cases, perhaps `Exit Sub`
End Select

' Now you need only one instance of the repetitive block
' You've got the right `ws` from above.

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
... and so on
```

If you are dealing with a repetitive `DIVISION - ## - ....` pattern, then you could refactor your `Select Case` into a separate function that parses the sheet name instead of listing all the possibilities as you currently do.

Comment: Thank you very much that solves the issue.  Spent all this time looking for a code word, but just needed to delete the stuff and move it to the end.  Again thank you.

Comment: You might even consider moving the repetitive block into its own `Sub` and passing that sub the `ws` as a parameter.

Comment: That would probably be a smart thing to do, and I might do it at a future time when I have a better understanding of VBA.  Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you have another answer that does that for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking to not repeat code is  great thing. In this case you can simply just do the following:

```
Case "DIVISION 21 - FIRE SUPPRESSION"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-21")

Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")

End Select

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value
```

But as you are learning about how to "trim down code", I wanted to cover also calling a sub with arguments, like so.

```
Sub SheetSelect()

Dim ws as worksheet 

Case "DIVISION 21 - FIRE SUPPRESSION"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-21")
Call DoStuff(ws)

Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")
Call DoStuff(ws)

End Select
End Sub

Sub DoStuff(ws As WorkSheet)

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
ws.Range("d" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Generic_Name.Value
ws.Range("e" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Manufacturer.Value
ws.Range("s" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxAuthor_Initials.Value
ws.Range("f" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxModel_Name.Value
ws.Range("k" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxProduct_Serial_Number.Value
ws.Range("g" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("j" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxColor.Value
ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxLocal_Locations.Value
ws.Range("l" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxFeatures.Value
ws.Range("h" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxComments.Value
ws.Range("m" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Name.Value
ws.Range("n" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Phone.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value

End Sub
```

I don't know what it accepted practice/best policy, but I often put separate subs in separate modules so that I don't have modules that are super long. I also have a "main" module which only calls each sub that does something. This allows me to comment out subs for debugging and re-introduce them one by one.

Eg:

```
Sub Main_Sub()

Call First_Task

'Call Second_Task ' Comment out "Second Task" for debugging till "First_Task" works as expected, this also allows for future debugging.

End Sub
```